# Bitmap and geographic coordinates

Tags: c#

I have an array of geographic coordinates. I must draw a circle on each geographic coordinate. And I must get a bitmap on which these circles located.

Bitmap size is also in geographic coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to read up on [map projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection), and pick a suitable one to either look for implementations of, or implement yourself.